# made a button to change the color of a div, but it goes white again

Tags: javascript, html

so to test a code I've written i wanted to test a button by trying to click it. Its supposed to turn a div into a random color. which it does but not a milisecond later its white again.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is the Code:

```
</div>
    <div id="GETResponse">drztu</div> 
        <button id="GETid" onclick="ChangeColor()">GET</button>   
        <button id="updateButton">Update</button>  
    </form>
</div>
<script>
function ChangeColor(){
    var divElement = document.getElementById("GETResponse");
    var randomColor ="#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    divElement.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The default type of a `button` is `submit` - Furthermore the snippet you've posted definitely isn't valid. How to create a [mre]

Comment: To expand on the above comment, the button is submitting the form causing the page to reload. As HTML is stateless, the `div` is reset to it initial state. You either need to change the buttons to `type="button"` to prevent the form submission (which may not be possible depending on your use case) or you will need to have a method of saving state between page loads, which can either be done server side, or locally using localStorage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With the button inside the form in the first implementation,

```
<button type="button|submit|reset">
```

Button has the above three types, where `type = submit` is the default value.
Clicking on it submits the form, which causes the page to reload and reset to the original state. Thus causing the div reset to original which background.

### With the button not inside the form in the second implementation,

Even though the button is not defined, since the button is not within the form, it does not reload the page

### Random Color Generate Algorithm

Even though provided algorithm works as expected but sometimes it does not generate the hex color of length 6.
so, we could do following the following to be consistent with the length of hex color

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16).padStart(6, "0")
```

### Implementation Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="header1">With Form</h1>
    <div>
      <form>
        <div id="GETResponse1">Change color here: 1</div> 
        <button id="GETid1" onclick="ChangeColor1()">GET</button>
      </form>
    </div>  

    <!-- Here even though type of button is not defined
    since button is not within the form, it does not reload the 
    page -->
    <h1 id="header2">Without Form</h1>
    <div>
        <div id="GETResponse2">Change color here: 2</div> 
        <button id="GETid2" onclick="ChangeColor2()">GET</button>
    </div>  

    <script>
      function ChangeColor1() {
        const divElement = document.getElementById('GETResponse1');
        const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        divElement.style.backgroundColor = '#'.concat(randomColor);
      }

      function ChangeColor2() {
        const divElement = document.getElementById('GETResponse2');
        const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16).padStart(6, "0");
        divElement.style.backgroundColor = '#'.concat(randomColor);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```